# change data between two table in erlang

Tags: erlang

I have this tables :

```
 -record(person, {id, firstname, lastname}).
  -record(person_backup, {id, firstname, lastname}).
```

I create table person_backup with :

```
   create_backup()
    mnesia:create_table(person_backup,[{disc_copies, [node()]},{attributes, record_info(fields, person)},
        {record_name, person}]).
```

I have also this function :

```
create_table_increment()->
    mnesia:create_table(my_auto_inc,[{type,set}]).
```

**I want to transfer data from person to person_backup with some modification :**

for example if table person has :

```
13  asma   chabani
14  nawel  jirard
15  ahme   bahri
```

the table person_backup became :

```
1  asma   chabani
2  nawel  jirard
3  ahme   bahri
```

I try with this code :

```
test()->

        Match=#person{_ = '_'},                               %Will match all records
    Fun = fun() ->
              List = mnesia:match_object(Match),
              lists:foreach(fun(X) ->
        NextKey = mnesia:dirty_update_counter(my_auto_inc,lastrec,1),

                              Update = X#person_backup{id=NextKey,firstname = #person.firstname,lastname=#person.lastname},
                                mnesia:write(Update)
                            end, List)
          end,
    mnesia:transaction(Fun).
```

but when I test I have this error :

```
1> model:test().
 {aborted,{combine_error,my_auto_inc,update_counter}}
```

I try also with this code :

test2()->

```
    Match=#person{_ = '_'},                               %Will match all records
Fun = fun() ->
          List = mnesia:match_object(Match),
          lists:foreach(fun(X) ->
                                NextKey = mnesia:dirty_update_counter(my_auto_inc,lastrec,1),

                           Update = X#person_backup{id=NextKey,firstname = #person.firstname,lastname=#person.lastname},
                            mnesia:write(Update)
                        end, List)
      end,
mnesia:transaction(Fun).
```

and it displays this error :

```
model:test2().
{aborted,{{badrecord,person_backup},
          [{model,'-test2/0-fun-0-',1},
           {lists,foreach,2},
           {mnesia_tm,apply_fun,3},
           {mnesia_tm,execute_transaction,5},
           {erl_eval,do_apply,5},
           {shell,exprs,6},
           {shell,eval_exprs,6},
           {shell,eval_loop,3}]}}
```

Comment: What do you get if you run `mnesia:table_info(my_auto_inc, type).` in your Erlang shell?

Comment: 6> mnesia:table_info(my_auto_inc, type).
set

Comment: Hm, it was just an idea, because [update_counter doesn't work on ordered_set tables](http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-bugs/2011-November/002643.html), but it seems allright...

Comment: juste I want that someone verify with me the function test()

Answer (score 1):

You have created the person_backup table using record person and while writing to it you are using person_backup record which results in the error.